# sql - add a column to table whose value is greater than specified value

Tags: sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE Article
(
     ArCode CHAR(5) LIKE A% PRIMARY KEY, 
     ArName VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,  
     Rate NUMBER(8, 2), 
     Quantity NUMBER(4) >= 0 DEFAULT 0, 
     Class CHAR(1) CHECK(Class IN('A', 'B', 'C'))
);
```

Here I want to add a column named `Quantity` whose values must be greater than or equal to zero or default to zero. Also, a column `ArCode` which should start with `A`; Is the above code syntactically correct?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: @marc_s would you answer it only if I tag RDBMS ?

Comment: It's not about whether I would answer or not - but the **SQL** language (as standardized) is often not very clear, and many things will depend on the **actual RDBMS you're using** - so tagging what RDBMS you're using is just **good practice** so that you get proper, suitable responses for your question

Comment: Oh! Actually I'm new to this DBMS and SQL (beginner) so not sure about any other details.. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on your db backend.
But I'd say you would need a CHECK function like for the Class column.

My guess (untested as I don't have an SQL db handy right now) would be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Article
(
     ArCode CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (ArCode LIKE 'A%'),
     ArName VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,  
     Rate NUMBER(8, 2), 
     Quantity NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 0 CHECK (Quantity >= 0), 
     Class CHAR(1) CHECK(Class IN('A', 'B', 'C'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the RDBMS that you're using - but in general, in `ANSI SQL` you can use check constraints to limit the allowed values.

You can find some general information about it in this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint

and you can look for your specifics for the RDBMS that you're using.